# Specific alignment with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to make a table similar to this one:
[image]

I am trying to do that with siunitx package but I have trouble with alignment - I don't know how to align numbers to the left and ignore decimal dot alignment when I also want to have bases of 10 nicely aligned like on the picture.

My code:

```
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4, output-decimal-marker = {,}, exponent product = \cdot, inter-unit-product={}\cdot{}, table-number-alignment = left, table-figures-exponent=1}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|S[table-format = 9.10(2)e2]s[table-unit-alignment = left]|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Název} & Zn. & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hodnota} \\ 
\hline
Atomová hmotnostní          & $ m_{\textrm{u}} $                & 1.66053886(28)e-27            & \si{\kilogram} \\
Avogadrova                  & $ N_{\textrm{A}} $                & 6.0221415(10)e23              & \si{\per\mole} \\
Bohrův poloměr              & $ a_{\textrm{0}} $                & 0.5291772108(18)e-10          & \si{\meter} \\
Elementární náboj           & $ e $                         & 1.60217653(14)e-19            & \si{\coulomb} \\
Faradayova                  & $ F $                         & 96485.3383(83)                & \si{\coulomb\per\mole} \\
Gravitační                  & $ G $                         & 6.6742(10)e-11                & \si{\newton\square\meter\per\square\kilogram} \\
Permeabilita vakua          & $ \mu_{\textrm{0}} $          & 4\pi e-7                      & \si{\newton\per\square\ampere} \\
Permitivita vakua           & $ \varepsilon_{\textrm{0}} $  & {$ 1/\mu_{\textrm{0}}c $}     & \si{\farad\per\meter} \\
Planckova                   & $ h $                         & 6.6260673(11)e-34             & \si{\joule\second} \\
Planckova redukovaná        & $ \hbar $                     & 1.05457168(18)e-34            & \si{\joule\second} \\
Plynová molární             & $ R_{\textrm{m}} $                & 8.314471(15)                  & \si{\joule\per\mole\per\kelvin} \\
Rychlost světla ve vakuu    & $ c $                         & 299792458                     & \si{\meter\per\second} \\
Stefanova-Boltzmanova       & $ \sigma $                        & 5.670400(40)e-8               & \si{\meter\kelvin} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

It's output:
[image]

Any idea how to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it this alignment that you want? I plit the number column into a left aligned column for the mantissa and an S column for the 10 powers part:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{siunitx, array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{amsmath}


    \begin{document}

 \sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4, output-decimal-marker = {,}, exponent-product = \cdot, inter-unit-product={} · {}, table-number-alignment = left, table-figures-exponent=1}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{ \multicolumn{2}{>{$}l<{$}}{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c| >{$}l<{$}@{${} · {}\mkern-22mu$}S[table-format =1 e-2, table-number-alignment = left]@{\hskip0.2em}l|}%S[table-unit-alignment = left]
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Název} & Zn. & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Hodnota} \\
\hline
Atomová hmotnostní & $ m_{\textrm{u}} $ & 1.66053886(28) & e-27 & \si{\kilogram} \\
Avogadrova & $ N_{\textrm{A}} $ & 6.0221415(10) & e23 & \si{\per\mole} \\
Bohrův poloměr & $ a_{\textrm{0}} $ & 0.5291772108(18) & e-10 & \si{\meter} \\
Elementární náboj & $ e $ & 1.60217653(14) & e-19 & \si{\coulomb} \\
Faradayova & $ F $ & \specialcell{96485.3383(83)} & \si{\coulomb\per\mole} \\
Gravitační & $ G $ & 6.6742(10) & e-11 & \si{\newton\square\meter\per\square\kilogram} \\
Permeabilita vakua & $ \mu_{\textrm{0}} $ & 4π& e-7& \si{\newton\per\square\ampere} \\
Permitivita vakua & $ \varepsilon_{\textrm{0}} $ & \specialcell{1/\mu_{\textrm{0}}c } & \si{\farad\per\meter} \\
Planckova & $ h $ & 6.6260673(11) & e-34 & \si{\joule\second} \\
Planckova redukovaná & $ \hbar $ & 1.05457168(18) & e-34 & \si{\joule\second} \\
Plynová molární & $ R_{\textrm{m}} $ & \specialcell{8.314471(15)} & \si{\joule\per\mole\per\kelvin} \\
Rychlost světla ve vakuu & $ c $ & \specialcell{299792458} & \si{\meter\per\second} \\
Stefanova-Boltzmanova & $ σ$ & 5.670400(40) & e-8 & \si{\meter\kelvin} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost what I want. I have only added these numbers into \num{} and made column for the 10 powers without dots in each row but only while needed and I am satisfied.

Comment: Oh! yes, I forgot about the rows without dots. I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: @Tomas: I've modified  the code to add a `\specialcell` command for the rows which don't require a dot. Please see if it's fine for you.